# Should binding to Path.Data property work?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

**EDIT: Note! This turned out to be a typo in my code**

[According to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.data.aspx) , Path.Data appears to be bindable. But I am not sure how to read the Depenedency Property Information part of the msdn page. Is AffectsRender and AffectsMeasure be enough for my use?

If I use x:Name to directly assign it, the geometry appears

```
var curve = new GeometryGroup();
curve.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(0, 0), new Point(20, 20)));
curve.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(0, 20), new Point(20, 0)));
CurveGraph.Data = curve;
```

This works fine. Draws a nice "X".

However, if I have a dependency property of type GeometryGroup in the ViewModel

```
var curve = new GeometryGroup();
curve.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(0, 0), new Point(20, 20)));
curve.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(0, 20), new Point(20, 0)));
GeometryData= curve;
```

dp :

```
public GeometryGroup GeometryData
    {
        get { return (GeometryGroup)GetValue(GeometryDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GeometryDataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GeometryDataProperty =  DependencyProperty.Register("GeometryDataProperty", typeof(GeometryGroup), typeof(MiniTrendVm), new UIPropertyMetadata(new GeometryGroup()));
```

...then it didn't work. Nothing happens. No "X".

xaml :

```
<Path Data="{Binding GeometryData}" x:Name="CurveGraph" Stroke = "{Binding StrokeColor}" StrokeThickness = "2" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
```

Should this work? Have I fat fingered something? Or can't the Data property be set this way? The brush was databound in both cases, so I know that the datacontext is correctly set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DependencyProperty` is registered as `"GeometryDataProperty"` which should be `"GeometryData"`. Not quite sure if this actually breaks the binding. **Edit:** Recent tests by H.B. reveal that this probably is indeed the cause. Binding that property is possible.

Comment: Why are you talking about yourself in the 3rd person?

Comment: @svick: Just for the heck of it :)

Comment: recent tests by svick seem to indicate this can confuse some people :-)

Comment: XProperty, X has to match with what you are binding otherwise it might not work as expected

Comment: @anvarbek raupov: Not entirely true, the CLR-Wrappers are optional, you can bind directly to a DependencyProperty using its registered name, however if you do not do that the property should be registered with the same name as the CLR-property to avoid accidentally binding to the CLR-property which does not provide change notifications. Further the word `property` does not need to be used, the field name is completely arbitrary, calling it `???Property` is just a convention.

Comment: ...and just thinking about how close I was to NOT include the dependency property plumbing code because I thought it cluttered up the question. I've written dep props like a gazillion times, but this time I edited it in a few steps and just lost rhythm.

Comment: @Tormod: If you use VisualStudio just stick to using the `propdp` snippet and things like that are unlikely to happen. (I modified mine a bit to have the field on top and removed the unnecessary comment line)

Comment: I know I know. I should've created it from scratch instead of editing it. I use the Resharper live template. R# also allows the template to enter the name of the surrounding type. In my case "MiniTrend".