# Binding on Path.Data Property at a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, controls

I want to make the same as in an previos question from 2011:
[Should binding to Path.Data property work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573130/should-binding-to-path-data-property-work) but my problem is that i got any other mistake and i don't understand witch one. I'm relay looking since a view days what i am doing wrong, but i must be blind ...

Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Path Data="{Binding GeometryData}" x:Name="CurveGraph" Stroke = "Black" StrokeThickness = "2" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

CustomControl.cs:

```
public class CustomControl : Control    
{

static CustomControl()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl)));
    CustomControl tmp = new CustomControl();
    tmp.Build();
}

public GeometryGroup Build()
{
    var curve = new GeometryGroup();
    curve.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(0, 0), new Point(20, 20)));
    curve.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(0, 20), new Point(20, 0)));
    new CustomControl().GeometryData = curve;
    return curve;
}

private GeometryGroup GeometryData
{
    get { return (GeometryGroup)GetValue(GeometryDataProperty); }
    set { SetValue(GeometryDataProperty, value); }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GeometryDataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("GeometryData", typeof(GeometryGroup), typeof(CustomControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(new GeometryGroup()));
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <ctl:CustomControl x:Name="Curve"/>
</Grid>
```

That's it. The Main Window.xaml.cs only got his constructor. But i really don't know what the problem is. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to create a temporary CustomControl instance in the (static) class constructor and call the Build method, which sets the `GeometryData` on yet another temporary instance.

Instead, add an instance constructor that initializes `GeometryData` on the current instance. Also make `GeometryData` public.

```
public class CustomControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GeometryDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "GeometryData", typeof(GeometryGroup), typeof(CustomControl));

    public GeometryGroup GeometryData
    {
        get { return (GeometryGroup)GetValue(GeometryDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GeometryDataProperty, value); }
    }

    static CustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl)));
    }

    public CustomControl()
    {
        Build();
    }

    public void Build()
    {
        var curve = new GeometryGroup();
        curve.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(0, 0), new Point(20, 20)));
        curve.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(0, 20), new Point(20, 0)));
        GeometryData = curve;
    }
}
```

Besides that you would either use a `TemplateBinding` in the ControlTemplate

```
<Path Data="{TemplateBinding GeometryData}" ... />
```

or specify the binding source like

```
<Path Data="{Binding GeometryData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ... />
```

Comment: The temporary instance was only one of thousands try to get it work. But I also tried to call the build function from the MainWindow.xaml.cs and at that point it's called from the same instants as well, doesn't it?

Comment: See my edit. Build is now a public instance method that can be called on a CustomControl instance, e.g. in the MainWindow's code behind. Thus you could probably save the instance constructor.